# How to fix unbalanced parentheses here?

Tags: fortran

Operating System : Windows  10

```
Program blue
implicit none
INTEGER :: Count = 0, OpenStatus, InputStatus
CHARACTER(20) :: FileName
REAL :: Temperature, Volume, SumOfTemps = 0.0, SumOfTemps2 = 0.0, &
SumOfVols = 0.0, SumOfProds = 0.0, MeanTemperature, &
MeanVolume, Slope, Y_Intercept

WRITE (*, '(1X, A)', advance = "NO"), "Enter name of data file:"
READ *, FileName
OPEN (unit = 15, File = FileName, STATUS = "OLD", &
IOSTAT = OpenStatus)

IF (OpenStatus > 0) stop "*** Cannot open the file ***"

100 format(4X, F4.1, T13, F4.1)
110 format(1X, A11, A10)
120 format(1X, F8.1, F12.1)
print *
print 110, "Temperature", "Volume"
print 110, "===========", "======"

DO
read(unit = 15, FMT = 100, IOSTAT = InputStatus,
& Temperature, Volume)

IF (InputStatus > 0) stop "*** Input error ***"
IF (InputStatus < 0) exit

print 120, Temperature, Volume
Count = Count + 1
SumOfTemps = SumOfTemps + Tempearture
SumOfTemps2 = SumOfTemps2 + Temperature ** 2
SumOfVols = SumOfVols + Volume
SumOfProds = SumOfProds + Temperature * Volume

END DO

MeanTemperature = SumOfTemps / REAL(Count)
MeanVolume = SumOfVols / REAL(Count)
Slope = (SumOfProds - SumOfTemps * MeanVolume) / &
(SumOfTemps2 - SumOfTemps * MeanTemperature)
Y_Intercept = MeanVolume - Slope * MeanTemperature

print 130, Slope, Y_Intercept
130 format(//1X, "Equation of least-square line is" &
           /1X, " y =", F5.1, "x + ", F5.1, &
           /1X, "where X is temperature and y is volume")

close (15)

END program blue
```

The syntax was so long that it was divided and started.
Fil5-1.dat file was created by running until IF(OpenStatus> 0) stop. Then IF(OpenStatus> 0) stop Stop the previous statement. After saving from 100 format to end do. 
So I get an unbalanced parentheses error, how do I change it?

Comment: Please show the exact error message from the compiler, in particular showing which part is upsetting it. (If it's the statement `read(unit = 15, FMT = 100, IOSTAT = InputStatus,` then I'm with the compiler there.)

Comment: probably trying to compile a free format source file as fixed source form

Comment: If you save Program blue to end do and run the program, an error occurs. The exact errors are PGF90-S-0155-Unexpected continuation (t.f90: 31), PGF90-S-0023-Syntax error-Unbalanced paraentheses (t.f90: 30).

Comment: It says it is line 31. You should tell us which line is line 31.

Comment: Your line continuation in

      `read(unit = 15, FMT = 100, IOSTAT = InputStatus,
    & Temperature, Volume)`

is wrong.The `&` should be at the end of the line as you do elsewhere. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What compiler are you using and what fortran standard are you using? In your code I see no indentation and some DO statements are capitals while some dont'. Try to write your code in a "standard" way.

You are probably using the fixed form of fortran as you are using & for new lines. Probably if you use a modern fortran standard you can get away without using the & and so simplifying brakets managment

Comment: This is the  free source form. The fixed one is different.

Comment: Use Fortran 90. Create a program by accessing the school server remotely. If capital letters are standard, I will use capital letters. Looking at the textbook, it says vi editor and putty, but I don't know if this is the compiler.

Comment: If you are not using fixed form Fortran then you can remove all the & in the code since there is no limit on line lenght.

Comment: When I run the program, I use the pgf90 t.f90 command, and when I use vi, I put f90 at the end, so it seems that the compiler name I use is f90.

Comment: The compiler you are using is pgf90. By default .f90 files are considered free form fortran files, hence you can delete the & symbols and write everything in the same line

Comment: @Edo98 There *is* a line length limit in free form as well. Just somewhat bigger.